# Why is my M1 Mac waking up every hour or so?

Tags: macos

How can I disable following maintenance scheduled wakes on macOS Monterey?

```
$ pmset -g log | grep "Wake Request"
…
2022-08-25 06:41:48 -0400 Wake Requests         [*process=PowerUIAgent request=Maintenance deltaSecs=3598 wakeAt=2022-08-25 07:41:46 info="com.apple.obc"]
```